# Debug LINQ statement in Visual Basic for “item with the same key has already been added” error

Tags: vb.net, linq

I need to fix some code that I didn't write and without documentation. The LINQ statement that follows sometimes throws the exception  “item with the same key has already been added” but I haven't found a way to figure out where it throws the duplicate.

```
Return Me.Values.SelectMany(
    Function(obj) obj.Users.Values.Distinct()).
        Where(Function(u) u.UserIsInbox = False).
        Distinct().
        ToDictionary(Function(u) u.Code, Function(u) u)
```

I also tried to have all the contents of the collections printed but I had no results.
How can I do?

Comment: I'm sure it throws in `ToDictionary`. Usually this filtering before `ToDictionary` is done not with `Distinct` but with `GroupBy`. Or alternatively you can provide `IEqualityComparer` to `Distinct` which will use `u.Code` to compare items. Or override `Equals`  for your object.

Comment: Your last `.Distinct()` must produce a sequence where each element has unique `u.Code`. Instead it produces a sequence of unique instances of `u`, even if many of them have the same `Code`.